# Bind LINQ result to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

From this LINQ query,

```
 var usernames = (from A in logList orderby A.FirstName select new 
  UserName { Users = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = Convert.ToInt32(A.Id) }).Distinct();
```

I want to bind Users name with `ID` to `ComboBox`.

```html
 <ComboBox  Name="cmbUserName" Height="30"  
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,64,614,0"/>
```

Linq result shows,

[image]

Inside each list items contain ID and Users.

[image]

Comment: You could either use `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` Or use `DisplayMemberPath`. Check the duplicate question for example.

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes, Its working. One more question. how set zeroth possition "Select" text in Combobox?

Comment: Hi S Akbari, How to set "Select" in Combobox defult value?

Comment: You can set the `Text` property : Text="Select Item".

Comment: I have did that, but it is not happening. My code is like that,
 var usernames = (from A in logList orderby A.FirstName select new { Name = A.FirstName + " " + A.SurName, ID = A.Id }).Distinct();
 cmbUserName.ItemsSource = usernames;
            cmbUserName.SelectedIndex = 0;
<ComboBox  Name="cmbUserName" Height="30" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,64,614,0"/>